# Trying to get transfer_sub from apple but got invalid_request

Tags: authentication, transfer, apple-sign-in

I am trying to transfer users that use "Sign in with Apple" to another team by following the instructions here: [Transferring Your Apps and Users to Another Team](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/transferring_your_apps_and_users_to_another_team)

I am getting the access token perfectly fine but when I am trying to get the transfer_sub, I always got invalid_request. I am pretty sure the parameters I provide are correct. My concern is the order of the steps.

[Here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f) apple spesifically says:

> As part of preparing your data for the recipient team, you will need to generate a transfer identifier for all users in your database prior to initiating a transfer.

On the other hand [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667043?answerId=647963022#647963022) says:

> You cannot use the api "/auth/usermigrationinfo" of the URL before app transfer.

There is one opened issue on apple developer forum [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/654895?login=true) but no answer.

So in the end my questions are:

1. Which steps should be done before and after the transfer?
2. Can i get the transfer_sub for each user by sending a request to /usermigrationinfo with old team's client_secret even after the transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the transfer Id, which in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple) refers as `transfer_sub` is a bit tricky but you can extract it. Here are the steps:

1. Get the identity Token after sign-in in with Apple:

   ```
   func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
       if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
           if let identityTokenData = appleIDCredential.identityToken {
           let identityToken = String(data: identityTokenData, encoding: .utf8)
           // this is explained on the next step
           if let transferId = decodeIDTokenAndExtractTransferId(identityToken) {
                   print("Transfer ID: \(transferId)")
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then, we use the identity token to decode it and extract the JSON that contains the transfer id using the following logic:

   ```
   func decodeIDTokenAndExtractTransferId(_ idToken: String?) -> String? {
    guard let idToken = idToken else {
        return nil
    }

    let components = idToken.components(separatedBy: ".")
    guard components.count == 3 else {
        return nil
    }

    let payloadBase64 = components[1]
    guard let payloadData = base64UrlDecode(payloadBase64) else {
        return nil
    }

    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: payloadData, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
            return json["transfer_sub"] as? String
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error decoding ID token: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    return nil
   }

   func base64UrlDecode(_ base64Url: String) -> Data? {
    var base64 = base64Url
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")

    let remainder = base64.count % 4
    if remainder > 0 {
        base64.append(String(repeating: "=", count: 4 - remainder))
    }

    return Data(base64Encoded: base64)
   }
   ```

This JSON has the following keys inside it where you can get the value that you need:

iss, sub, aud, iat, exp, nonce, nonce_supported, email, email_verified, is_private_email, real_user_status, **transfer_sub**

You can read what each one of them does [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple).